# Bayesian calibration of computer simulations - Likelihood function calculation

Tags: bayesian, simulation, calibration

I am starting to study Bayesian calibrations of computer models. I am not a statistician and just starting to learn so bear with me if I do not use the correct terminology.

The general approach is based on [Kennedy and O’Hagan, ‘Bayesian Calibration of Computer Models’](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Bayesian-calibration-of-computer-models-Kennedy-O%27Hagan/c67ff56d0f5d252e80b48de917e3fc71e47d13a0), but I am following specifically [Van Oijen, Rougier, and Smith, ‘Bayesian Calibration of Process-Based Forest Models’](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/15870058/) as it is a bit easier to follow.

For one single calibration parameter $t$ and boundary condition $x$, the approach states that the observation values can be described as

$$
y(x) = M(x,t) + \delta(x) + E(x)
$$

Where $y(x)$ is the measured data, $M(x,t)$ is the result of a computer simulation, $E(x)$ is the error of the measurement, $x$ is some boundary condition and $\delta(x)$ is the error of the model.

If I assume that the model is ‘precise’ than I can rewrite
$$
y(x) = M(x, t) + E(x)
$$

If the set of $n$ measurements is Y and the prior pdf is $p(t)$ I can write
$$
p(t|Y) = \frac{p(Y|t) p(t)}{p(Y)}
$$

To calculate the likelihood $p(Y|t)$, the paper states that, for a specific value of $t$, $\theta$:
$$
p(Y|\theta) = p(E = Y - M(\theta))
$$
This is because (quote):

*“A common assumption when choosing the likelihood is that θ, were it to be known, would provide a perfect match between the process model output and the true value from the system. In this case the observed differences between the two are attributable to measurement error in Y.”*

The way I read it, but do not understand it, is: the probability of obtaining those observation, given $\theta$, is the same as the probability of the error being equal to $Y - M(\theta)$

Questions:

- Is the statement correct? Can it be rephrased more clearly?
- If so, how can I derive it more formally?
- I do not know the error. How can I can calculate the probability?

If I understand correctly, the above methodology is not related to approximate bayesian computation, because we do have an expression for the likelihood, albeit not analytical.

I hope the above makes sense.